# ALTER TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT

Tags: oracle, constraints, alter

Error starting at line 35 in command:

```
ALTER TABLE lee_person
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_person_type 
  CHECK(CASE WHEN UPPER(person_type) = 'EMPLOYEE'
             THEN employment_date IS NOT NULL 
             AND  manager_id IS NOT NULL
             WHEN UPPER(person_type) = 'CLIENT'
             THEN employment_date IS NULL 
             AND  manager_id IS NULL                
        END)
```

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a `CASE` like you're trying to do (`CASE WHEN condition-A THEN condition-B AND condition-C`).

It looks like you want to enforce the following:

1. If the `person_type` is `employee` (case-insensitive), `employment_date` and `manager_id` must be `NOT NULL`.
2. If the `person_type` is `client` (case-insensitive), `employment_date` and `manager_id` must be `NULL`.

If that's the case, try something this instead:

```
ALTER TABLE lee_person
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_person_type
  CHECK ( (UPPER(person_type) = 'EMPLOYEE' AND
           employment_date IS NOT NULL AND
           manager_id IS NOT NULL)
       OR (UPPER(person_type) = 'CLIENT' AND
           employment_date IS NULL AND
           manager_id IS NULL)
  )
```

I've tested this and it works.

Note that the only `person_type` values it allows are `employee` and `client` (case-insensitive). If you want to allow other types (with or without `employment_date` or `manager_id` restrictions) you'll need to tack on additional `OR` conditions.